# DELETE on a heap table

Tags: sql-server, delete, heap

Is there any way to deallocate empty pages on a heap table during a delete operation other than putting an exclusive lock on the table or rebuilding it? None of these options are acceptable for my production environment.

Answer (score 11):

Sure, put a clustered index on it. Tables with a clustered index will automatically deallocate space.

Otherwise, you're looking at:

- ALTER TABLE (mytablename) REBUILD - which takes it offline
- Doing deletes with TABLOCK hints
- TRUNCATE TABLE (mytablename)

I know some folks think it's trendy, but heaps just aren't a good fit for active OLTP systems that have to deal with deletes (which cause the empty space problem) and updates (which cause the forwarded fetches problem.)

Comment: Yes, I have been deleting with TABLOCK thinking that it will put a shared lock which is OK for my environment. But when checking locks on the table I`ve found out that it put an exclusive lock for DELETE operation

Comment: Yep, when you say lock the table, that isn't sharing. :-D

Answer (score 1):

You can reclaim the space by shrinking.

From [SQLskills SQL101: Why does my heap have a bunch of empty pages?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sqlskills-sql101-why-does-my-heap-have-a-bunch-of-empty-pages/) by Paul Randal (emphasis added):

> On the extreme end (in my opinion), you could **reclaim the empty heap space using a shrink operation**. Shrink won’t free up space inside pages as it moves them (with the exception of compacting LOB pages as it goes – somewhat unsuccessfully depending on which version and build you’re on – see KB 2967240), but **it will remove empty pages rather than moving them.** This will effectively shrink the heap after a large delete, but with the usual caveats about shrink causing index fragmentation and generally being an expensive, slow operation to perform.